# Is the Universe created from Vacuum Fluctuations?

Tags: cosmology, universe, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, holographic-principle, black-hole-thermodynamics

I would be interested to hear what people think about this idea for a paper.

It has been speculated that the universe is a zero-energy vacuum fluctuation (E.P.Tryon Nature 1973). I attempt to show how matter might be continually created in the universe from quantum fluctuations using the uncertainty and holographic principles. I derive a unique linear cosmology with a scale $R = ct$ where $t$ is the age of the universe. I show that the annihilation time of a quantum fluctuation depends exponentially on $R$ so that there is an effective cosmological horizon at that distance. Previously it has been found (F.Melia et al.) that a linear Big-Bang model fits the Hubble expansion data remarkably well. Additionally such a model does not suffer from the classical horizon and flatness problems and so does not require a period of cosmological inflation.

We start from Heisenberg's quantum uncertainty principle

\begin{equation}
\Delta x \Delta p \sim \hbar \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta x$ is the uncertainty in position and $\Delta p$ is the uncertainty in momentum.

We assume a fluctuation with temperature $T$ that is localised in a region of space with linear dimension of order $R$ so that we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta x &\sim& R \tag{2} \\ 
\Delta p &\sim& \frac{k_B T}{c}.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, by substituting (2) into (1), we find the following relationship for the temperature $T$ given by

\begin{equation}
T \sim \frac{\hbar c}{k_B R}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

This temperature is analogous to the Hawking temperature for a black hole of radius $R$ given by

\begin{equation}
T = \frac{\hbar c}{4 \pi k_B R}. \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Let us assume that there is some type of spherical horizon around us at radius $R$.

Following the holographic principle, we hypothesise that the entropy inside the horizon is given by the maximal-entropy black-hole Bekenstein-Hawking formula:

\begin{equation}
S = \frac{k_B A}{4\ell_P^2}. \tag{5}
\end{equation}
where the area $A=4 \pi R^2$ and the Planck length $\ell_P=\sqrt{G\hbar/c^3}$.

Let us assume the mass-energy inside the horizon obeys the Einstein equation

\begin{equation}
E = M c^2. \tag{6}
\end{equation}

Finally let us assume that the system obeys the fundamental thermodynamic relationship

\begin{equation}
dE = TdS \tag{7}
\end{equation}
where $E$ is the internal energy, $T$ is the temperature and $S$ is the entropy.

By substituting (4), (5), (6) into (7) and integrating we find that

\begin{equation}
R = \frac{2 G M}{c^2}. \tag{8}
\end{equation}

Perhaps unsurprisingly (8) is identical to the Schwarzschild black hole radius formula.

In order to investigate how the space inside the horizon expands we assume Friedmann's equation for a homogeneous and isotropic universe. Since the horizon radius $R$ is assumed to be the scale of a region of space then we expect it to expand with the universal scale factor $a(t)$ such that $R=a(t)R_0$. Therefore we can write the Friedmann equation in terms of radius $R$. For simplicity we assume a spatially flat universe without an explicit cosmological constant term so that we have

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\dot R}{R}\right)^2 = \frac{8 \pi G \rho}{3}. \tag{9}
\end{equation}

Now the mass $M$ inside the spherical volume enclosed by the horizon at radius $R$ is given by

\begin{equation}
M = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3 \rho. \tag{10}
\end{equation}

By eliminating the mass density $\rho$ between (9) and (10), and also the mass $M$ using (8), we find

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\dot R}{R}\right)^2 = \frac{c^2}{R^2}. \tag{11}
\end{equation}

Equation (11) has the linear solution

\begin{equation}
R = c t. \tag{12}
\end{equation}

So far we have assumed that there exists some type of horizon at radius $R$. In order to complete this analysis we must investigate the nature of this horizon.

Let us assume that at time $t_0$ a quantum fluctuation occurs as described by equations (1,2). In order for the fluctuation to annihilate, a light signal that starts at the origin at time $t_0$ must reach the horizon at time $t_1$.

The comoving distance $D_0$ travelled by such a light beam is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
D_0 &=& \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{c dt}{a(t)} \tag{13} \\
&=& c t_0 \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{dt}{t} \\
&=& R_0 \ln{\frac{t_1}{t_0}}.
\end{eqnarray}
where $a(t)=R/R_0=t/t_0$.

Thus the annihilation time $t_1$ is given by

\begin{equation}
t_1 = t_0 \exp{\frac{D_0}{R_0}}. \tag{14}
\end{equation}

Equation (14) shows that the annihilation time $t_1$ increases exponentially with $D_0$ with a length scale $R_0$. Thus, for all practical purposes, we do have a cosmological horizon at radius $R_0$.

Comment: Pro tip: use `\tag{n}` to get a numbered equation, rather than `\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [peer review](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/50583), non-mainstream physics and/or [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are off-topic here. Please ask a specific question about established physics instead of asking us to comment on ideas.

Comment: As you have probably realized already this is not a good site to bounce ideas for a paper. The question has been around for a long time and I find it quite interesting, but to avoid closing you need to forego presenting your own ideas and instead ask a more targeted question about some aspect of this concept